# Shiny server: output only updates after clicking in textInput box

Tags: r, wordpress, cross-domain, shiny, postmessage

I have a Wordpress website where persons can log in and do a quiz. The quiz is actually a Shiny app that is running on a different server and domain.

You can go to the page (www.allmoocs.nl/test) and see for yourselves. The test login is: "test" and password "test@allmoocs". With some excellent examples found on this forum I managed to get user data from Allmoocs into a textInput box in de UI of the Shiny app.

If you click in the textbox with the user data, hit enter and push the "Send" button the result shows your user data. Now, this is almost exactly what I want **except for the clicking and hitting in the text box**. Later on I want to hide the text box and user data should be added automatically when someone finishes the quiz.

All code can be viewed here:  https://github.com/witusj/Quizii/tree/master/Quizii_V3

I hope it's a small thing and am confident to a certain degree that some of you can enlighten me on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I found it (and it was so simple)! Just added "\n" to the string that was sent from Wordpress to Shiny.

P.S. Oh, and apparently you need to add Shiny.unbindAll() to the beginning of the javascript and end it with Shiny.bindAll(). The mechanics of these two functions are not completely clear to me, but maybe someone knowledgable can expatiate on this topic.